# Stackoverflow when concatenating lambda expressions

Tags: c#

If I use

```
Func<int, bool> f = x => false;
```

Then update:

```
f = x => f(x) || false;
```

Then

```
f(0)
```

causes a stackoverflow.

I do know the late evaluation cause the stackoverflow. But how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think it's solvable without creating a second variable. Are you encountering this in a real project? Or is it merely an interesting excercise?

Comment: you're endlessly recursively calling f()

Comment: Well, you've asked it to recurse endlessly - so that's what it does. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish here?

Comment: Basically this is to concatenate conditions from a list of items.

Comment: Try to wrap `Func` into an `Expression`, and work with expressions instead of with Funcs.

Comment: Do you want `f(x)` to call previous instance of `f`, so that the call in essence should result to `false || false`? Try having two Func variables, `f1` and `f2`, and call one from another.

Comment: @Wouter So you'd have a `List<Func<int, bool>>`, and you want to combine them all with logical OR into one big combined `Func<int, bool>`? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: The problem is that `f` is being captured. You need to put `f` into a temporay varible first.

Comment: "concatenate conditions" - sounds like you might want to use [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I fixed is using listOfStuff.Any(condition). I was just trying to "build" one big or-condition. But this works ok. The capturing of f into a temporary variable also works